# Website scroll down effect in Gogoro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I searched for this scroll down effect but can't get useful information.

How can I do the scroll down effect in http://www.gogoro.com/#/smarter (the mobile phone section), where the phone image fixed in the browser window while it's content is changing along with the page scroll.

Is that done by javascript or CSS?

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting is a parallax scrolling effect. Do a search for ["Parallax Scrolling libraries"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=parallax%20scroll%20libraries&pc=MOZI&form=MOZSBR), there's lots of tools out there to help you, and it's not too hard to roll your own either. For instance, the background parallax effect found on [this site](http://tusksoft.com/) is just a very few lines of pure javascript- no library needed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var background = document.getElementById("background");
        var parallax = function() {
            var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
            background.style.marginTop = (-28 - scrollTop / 120) + "%";
        };
        window.onscroll = parallax;
        parallax();
    })();
</script>
```